# NSInteger != nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How can I check that the NSInteger is valid?

```
NSInteger previousScore = [[self score] integerValue];
    if (previousScore != nil) {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: removed salutation: "Thanks in advance.", don't do it next time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to check for validity in your code, you'd do something like:

```
NSNumber *previousScore = [self score];

if ( previousScore != nil ) {
  NSInteger previousScoreValue = [previousScore integerValue];
  // do something
}
```

This works as you are getting back an object, not a primitive value.

Comment: Thanks. Great idea. I am reading in and out of plist so everything in the array has to be NSNumber.

Answer (score 13):

`NSInteger` isn't an object. It's simply a typecasted primitive `int`. Therefore, it will never be `nil`. Just treat it the same as if you were using an `int` straight up.

**Edit:**
To expound upon Cesar's comment, on 64-bit systems `NSInteger` is actually a `long` and on 32-bit systems it's an `int`.

Comment: defined as: #if __LP64__
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
endif

Comment: Actually by default in many situations an NSInteger will be nil, because nil is the same as zero... you may well get a compiler warning though.  In the sample code given previousScore would be 0 (nil) if [self score] came back nil...

Comment: unfortunately, nil is 0. try "po nil ==0" in the debugger. It print "true"